# Buenas, quiero pasar los datos que aparecen en mi tabla a un formulario en otra página, estoy que lo hago a si y no me jala

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<form role="form" name="boton" action="../cd/pre.php" method="POST"">

            <table class="table">
                <div class="alert alert-info">
        <h2>Mis Encuestas</h2>
        </div>
                <tr>
                    <th>Codigo</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th> 
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Consultar</th>


                </tr>
                <?php
                while ($lista=$rs->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH)) { 
                  //$_SESSION['id'] =$lista['idEncusta'];

                      echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$lista['idEncuesta'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$lista['NomEncuesta'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$lista['fecha'].'</td>

                    <td> <input type="submit" name="boton" value="Ver"> </td>


                </tr>';

                }
                ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $lista['idEncuesta']; ?>">
                </table>

                     </form>
```

---

pre.php

```
<?php
require("conexion.php");
    $id=$_POST["id"];
//session_start();
 //$id=$_SESSION["id"];

     $alumno = "SELECT * FROM preguntas where(idEncuesta='$id')";
     $rs=$con->query($alumno);
 ?>
```

Comment: ¿Y el problema exacto es?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Por favor trata de dar formato a tu código con la herramienta que tienes al editar la descripción de tu pregunta que es un icono con forma de hoja de papel y un simbolo "<>" dentro de ella. Con esto se lee mejor tu código y más personas se interesan en ayudarte. Un saludo!

Comment: Si es posible suministra también una descripción con más detalles sobre lo que quieres lograr

Comment: ¿Estás enviando el formulario en el action a la página donde haces la consulta a la base de datos? Si es así nunca va a funcionar, es un problema de base, tienes que tener la consulta antes de intentar mostrarla rellenando el formulario, bien porque la hagas en la misma página o porque la incluyas, no hacer el select después de enviar el formulario con un dato de id que sacas del propio formulario.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias agregar el error que te muestran los logs? (en caso de que se muestre alguno).

Y suponiendo que se hace la consulta,podrias continuar con el manejo de session para mandar la info.

El codigo en tu **"pre.php"** quedaria algo asi.

```
<?php 
      session_start();
      require("conexion.php");
      $id = $_REQUEST[id]; //Request the info from index page

       $alumno = "SELECT * FROM preguntas where(idEncuesta='$id')";
      ?>
```

Recuerda que para utilizar las session despues de mandar el POST, en tu pagina destino agregas la instruccion **$_REQUEST[id];** sin usar comillas entre los corchetes. Incluso la puedes asignar a una variable de la siguiente forma.

para el query a la DB tambien puedes mandar el request directo algo asi

```
$alumno = "SELECT * FROM preguntas where(idEncuesta='$_REQUEST[id]')";
```

y funcionara adecuadamente.

Recomendaciones al codigo, trata de utilizar nombres/ids que reprecenten la funcionalidad del objeto.
En caso que no este funcionando el codigo, serviria agregar "que hace y que no hace el codigo".

Por lo que podrias 
1.- Revisar el "action" del form al momento que estas mandando la info.
2.- La manera de mandar la info con el "input hidden" usando la lista directamente. Podrias intentar cambiar la manera que estas asignando el valor algo asi:

```
<?php
            while ($lista=$rs->fetch_array(MYSQL_BOTH)) { 
              //$_SESSION['id'] =$lista['idEncusta'];

                  echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$lista['idEncuesta'].'</td>
                <td>'.$lista['NomEncuesta'].'</td>
                <td>'.$lista['fecha'].'</td>

                <td> <input type="submit" name="boton" value="Ver"> </td>


            </tr>';

            }
           echo ('<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$lista['idEncuesta'].'">'; ?>
```

Espero y sirva de algo. Asegurate que la variable de *$lista['idEncuesta']* se muestra adecuadamente con un Alert o un Echo en tu codigo. Nos dices como te fue y como lo resolviste.

Greetings!